# Access an element within a div

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to access an element using `xpath` by searching for a specific "value", here is the element :

```
<body>
    <div class="smenu" id="smenu4">
        <input tabIndex="-1" type="button" onclick="SearchEng" value="FindEng" />
        <!--> Lots of inputs <!-->
    </div>
</body>
```

The element I'm trying to access is `<input> tabIndex="-1" type="button" onclick="SearchEng" value="FindEng" </input>`

The xpath I tried using was : `//div[*/text()='smenu4']/descendant::input[@value='FindEng']`

But it won't be found. What's the proper `xpath` to it ?

I'm really new to `xpath` and I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Well, what do you want to access?

Comment: `//div[@id='smenu4']/input[@value='SearchEng']` ?

Comment: Well, I'd make it valid HTML first... that is not how you format an `<input>` element.  It should be `<input tabIndex="-1" type="button" onclick="SearchEng" value="FindEng" />`

Comment: i'll try that in a couple minutes, thanks

Comment: Once your HTML is valid, then you won't find `[@value='SearchEng']` because `@value` is set to `FindEng` and not `SearchEng`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments, firstly your HTML is invalid (it's not syntactically incorrect, but it's definitely not what you meant to do).  This is how the element should be formatted:

```
<!--Using Auto Close-->
<input tabIndex="-1" type="button" onclick="SearchEng" value="FindEng" />
<!--Using Manual Close-->
<input tabIndex="-1" type="button" onclick="SearchEng" value="FindEng"></input>
```

Once that is sorted out then your XPath is a bit of a mess...

You're using `text()='smenu4'` but your example HTML has `id="smenu4"`.  The `text()` node-test allows you to get the text within the element, so I don't believe this is going to work... instead try `@id='smenu4'`

Then you're searching for `[@value='SearchEng']` but `value` isn't set to `SearchEng`, it's set to `FindEng`.  So that probably should be `[@value='FindEng']`.

However, the entire thing could simply be written as...

```
//div[@id='smenu4' and input[@value='FindEng']]
```

---

**Update**

I've just come back to this and re-read the question, and the above XPath is incorrect, as it will return the `<div>` that the `input` is within.

This is what I think you want (assuming the `input` will be a direct descendant of the `div`)...

```
//div[@id='smenu4']/input[@value='FindEng']
```

Otherwise, if it's not necessarily a direct descendant then use...

```
//div[@id='smenu4']/descendant::input[@value='FindEng']
```

(Which I now admit is actually quite close to what you had originally, so I retract my "bit of a mess" statement... sorry about that!)

Comment: Hi, thank you for spending time on me despite my code being quite a mess ! I still wasn't able to find the element (using selenium WebDriver) but it must be a mistake on my part.

Comment: @Loukoum, see if my update makes any difference.  Unfortunately it's not easy to test XSLT... if you can, try using http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

Comment: A little nitpick, you wrote: _"The text() function "_ but `text()` is not a function, it is called a node-test (similar to `node()` etc) and it tests whether a node is a text node. It _looks_ like a function, but it isn't. And indeed, attributes do not have child nodes (and so, no text children), only a value.

Comment: Yes ! It does make a difference, I am able to select the element ! Thank you so much :-)  now I have an error saying I can't click it but that's still progress